# Consuming WebServices in Angular Frontend

Tags: asp.net, angular, web-services, wcf, .net-core

We have an requirement to consume (old ASMX) Web Services in our client side project (Angular).

1. The first issue is related to CORS as both projects (Web-Service / Frontend) are on different domains.
2. And secondly we don't have source code for that Web Service.

Is there is any possibility to host that Web Service in our domain? equally do we have any other possibilities?

**URL Rewrite** is one of the possibility to achieve that task.

1. Create **Sub Website** under **Default Website** in IIS.
2. Select **URL Rewrite**
3. Create new **In-Bound Rule** as below:

[image]

4. Web.Config will be like as below:

   ```
   <rewrite>
   <rules>
       <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" /> 
           <action type="Rewrite" url="http://domain1.com/sp/WebServices/json.asmx/GetPersonDetails" />
           <conditions>
               <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="GetPersonDetails" />
           </conditions>
       </rule>
       <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" /> 
           <action type="Rewrite" url="http://domain1.com/sp/WebServices/json.asmx/DropDownList" />
           <conditions>
               <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="DropDownList" />
           </conditions>
       </rule>
   </rules>
   ```

https://domain2.com/SportsPortalAPI/?q=DropDownList

https://domain2.com/SportsPortalAPI/?q=GetPersonDetails

In above we are invoking (02) Get method by using **query string** value **DropDownList** and **DropDownList** respectively

Comment: Which error does occur, please provide

Comment: Error: Access to fetch at 'domain1' from origin 'domain2' has been blocked by CORS policy.

Since we cannot make any changes in domain Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular [proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) for the web-service, but I wouldn't recommend that for permanent/production usage.

Comment: Sorry, we have Prod environment.